# Plesk DNS, directing subdomain to custom URL?

Tags: dns, plesk

I want to point a subdomain such as:

```
example.domain.com
```

to a URL like:

```
domain.com/something/this.php
```

How can I do this in Plesk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your scripts work, you can take one of two paths:

1. `Add Domain`, name it `example.domain.com` (yes, it will use one item of your domains limit), choose `Redirect` for `Hosting Type` and type target address there.
2. `Add Subdomain` and point its docroot folder to `/{domain.com docroot}/something/` folder. So `this.php` will be accessed as `example.domain.com/this.php` and `that.php` as `example.domain.com/that.php`